# Error creating IAM Role (test_role): MalformedPolicyDocument: Has prohibited field Resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to add a role to my instances in Terraform and I want to add a role with the `AmazonElasticFileSystemsUtils` policy attached to it. I got the JSON from the AWS console and added it to my terraform code, but it's giving me this error `Error creating IAM Role (test_role): MalformedPolicyDocument: Has prohibited field Resource` saying the policy is malinformed? Is there a different format that I have to use?

**main.tf**

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "role" {
  name = "test_role"
  path = "/"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:DescribeAssociation",
                "ssm:GetDeployablePatchSnapshotForInstance",
                "ssm:GetDocument",
                "ssm:DescribeDocument",
                "ssm:GetManifest",
                "ssm:GetParameter",
                "ssm:GetParameters",
                "ssm:ListAssociations",
                "ssm:ListInstanceAssociations",
                "ssm:PutInventory",
                "ssm:PutComplianceItems",
                "ssm:PutConfigurePackageResult",
                "ssm:UpdateAssociationStatus",
                "ssm:UpdateInstanceAssociationStatus",
                "ssm:UpdateInstanceInformation"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssmmessages:CreateControlChannel",
                "ssmmessages:CreateDataChannel",
                "ssmmessages:OpenControlChannel",
                "ssmmessages:OpenDataChannel"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2messages:AcknowledgeMessage",
                "ec2messages:DeleteMessage",
                "ec2messages:FailMessage",
                "ec2messages:GetEndpoint",
                "ec2messages:GetMessages",
                "ec2messages:SendReply"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticfilesystem:DescribeMountTargets"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:PutRetentionPolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect `assume_role_policy`. Assume role specifies what IAM entity (IAM role, user or AWS service) can assume the role. Not what permissions that entity has.

You should be using [iam_role_policy](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role_policy) to specify those permissions:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "test_policy" {
  name = "test_policy"
  role = aws_iam_role.role.id


  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:DescribeAssociation",
                "ssm:GetDeployablePatchSnapshotForInstance",
                "ssm:GetDocument",
                "ssm:DescribeDocument",
                "ssm:GetManifest",
                "ssm:GetParameter",
                "ssm:GetParameters",
                "ssm:ListAssociations",
                "ssm:ListInstanceAssociations",
                "ssm:PutInventory",
                "ssm:PutComplianceItems",
                "ssm:PutConfigurePackageResult",
                "ssm:UpdateAssociationStatus",
                "ssm:UpdateInstanceAssociationStatus",
                "ssm:UpdateInstanceInformation"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssmmessages:CreateControlChannel",
                "ssmmessages:CreateDataChannel",
                "ssmmessages:OpenControlChannel",
                "ssmmessages:OpenDataChannel"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2messages:AcknowledgeMessage",
                "ec2messages:DeleteMessage",
                "ec2messages:FailMessage",
                "ec2messages:GetEndpoint",
                "ec2messages:GetMessages",
                "ec2messages:SendReply"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticfilesystem:DescribeMountTargets"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:PutRetentionPolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}
```